# Access scale factor in d3's pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm using d3's pack layout with the default radius function. This scales the size of the circles so that everything fits into the container.

How can I access this scale factor?

Comment: The API doesn't expose this, so you would have to modify the source.

Comment: :-(. After playing around for a bit longer, it looks like the factor is not even a constant, i.e. `d.value/d.r` is not constant.

Comment: Ah, because it uses Math.sqrt as default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will display scaling factor in node's tooltip:

```
titles
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) {
        return (    "Scale factor  : " + (+d.value)/(d.r*d.r) + "\n" +
                    "Value: "  + d.value + "\n" +
                    "R: "  + d.r); 
    });
```

as in this [test example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FM2Lr/).

It looks the scaling factor is more or less the same for all leaf nodes in a circle pack, as illustrated in following two pictures:

[image]

[image]

However, it may vary for all other nodes!